# What is the equivalent python requests call for this wget?

Tags: python, post, wget, python-requests

I am trying to connect to a nessus server via XMLRPC using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). The following `wget` call works correctly:

```
wget -q --no-check-certificate \
     --post-data 'login=admin&password=adminpassword' \
     https://nessus.example.com:8834/login
```

I wanted to port it to python but:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.post("https://nessus.example.com:8834/login", 
        data={'user': 'admin', 'password': 'adminpassword'}, verify=False)
>>> r
<Response [500]>
>>> r.text
u'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">\r\n
<html><head>\r\n<title>500 Unknown Error</title></head>
<body><h1>Unknown Error</h1><p>An unknown error occured</p></body></html>'
```

I suspect that the way I pass the `POST` body is not correct (the error message does not help). I tried a few other variations (for instance `data='login=admin&password=adminpassword'`, to mimic the one in `wget`) -- same result.

The server side logs do not help either:

```
10.0.1.2 - - [28/Jan/2014:07:13:00 GMT] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 500
                 178 "-" "python-requests/2.0.0 CPython/2.7.6 Linux/3.10-2-amd64"
```

What is the correct way to pass this POST body?

Comment: The server side access log shows Internal Server Error `500`.. do you see any detail in error_log? Like apache error log?

Comment: @hashbrown: Nessus provides its own web server, the log I mentioned is the only one available

Comment: If I'm not wrong, your `data={'user': 'admin', 'password': 'adminpassword'}` will be encoded as `user=admin&password=adminpassword`, which is not the same than `login=admin&password=adminpassword` used with `wget`

Comment: why using 'user' as post parameter in requests and login in wget. Is this typo?

Comment: @hashbrown: you are right, I uncovered that literally a few seconds ago when going though a `tcpdump`of both requests. If you could copy that into a reply I will accept it so that you get the credit :)

Comment: @Abhishek: yes - please see my comment above

Comment: @doukremt: sorry, the 4th comment was intended to you :)

Comment: @doukremt: could you please copy/paste your comment into an answer so that I can accept it as the right one (even though we were a close tie :))